# How to get the size of the buffer in std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, stl, ofstream

The default size of the buffer is typically 8192 bytes, but this is implementation-dependent. How can I get the actual value of the current buffer size from an `std::ofstream` object?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you need it?

Comment: I am writing blobs of a specific size. I want to get all-or-nothing flushes (to disk) for a blob. I thought that if the buffer size is an integer multiple of the blob size, then all-or-nothing disk writes are likely. I don't want to write only a partial blob.

Comment: you're probably better off just disabling buffers https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf or use boost iostreams which give you more control

Comment: Disabling buffers results in unacceptable performance. I suppose I could buffer myself or use boost iostreams. Is it not possible to just get the buffer size used by std::ofstream? That would be much easier if it's possible.

Comment: nope, you might be able to set the size but even the behaviour there isn't specified and is different with each standard library

Comment: Couldn't you set the buffer size to a multiple of your blob size?

Comment: I concur with @AlanBirtles use boost asio. At least on windows when you select the right buffer sizes it will switch to DMA transfer if it can (I used it in the past for high bandwidth reads from network and writing to a disk cluster). Got 10Mbs at almost no CPU load.

Comment: Usually if you need this kind of control, you don't use fstreams in the first place, but use some lower-level API like `read/write`.  If it's important that your data actually reaches persistent storage then you're going to need additional steps like `fsync/fdatasync`.  Yes, there will be a performance hit, and that may just be the cost of correctness.

Comment: Windows says the most reliable way to do all-or-nothing writes is to write to a separate file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/deprecation-of-txf#applications-updating-a-single-file-with-document-like-data